# Newline in alert javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline, alert

I want to add a newline in alert message in javascript.

```
var al = $("#txt_noIncorrect").val().toString(); 

console.log(al);  // al='Incorrect amount!\nFor decimals, use point instead of virgule.'; 

alert(al);



alert('Incorrect amount!\nFor decimals, use point instead of virgule.')
```

First alert:
       [image]

Second alert:
      [image]

Why first alert does not put the newline?

Comment: sidenote: "point" and "virgule" are in French. The English terms for these punctuation marks are "dot" (or "full stop") and "comma".

Comment: Could you try `.text()` instead of `.val()`. And drop the `.toString()`

Comment: works fine in FF. Can make fiddle with example?

Comment: If your `console.log()` shows `\n` rather than a new line, then it means that the character \ is escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the \n with a new line character in Javascript using `.replace()`

`alert($("input[type='text']").val().replace(/\\n/g,"\n"));`

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j7XL6/)

---

### UPDATE

Here is a fiddle example with textarea instead of input text. [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j7XL6/1/)

Comment: Why did you use `input text`? You can't have newlines in there. Just use a `textarea`

Comment: this answer should do it right, because if the text assigned to the variable were as claimed, it would have worked. it must be a double slash in the text!

Comment: @putvande it was just to show a quick example, you can type in \n in the input text to see it work. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this `alert("Hello \r\nWorld");`

Comment: I tried before with \r\n and with <br/> but with no success.

Comment: This works. Someone who downvoted this must be a troll. There's no need to down vote an answer just because it didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

try this
alert("Hello \n World");